# Node Express: res.redirect broken when using proxy

Tags: node.js, express, apache2, reverse-proxy, passport.js

I have a node express app running behind a proxy, using Apache ProxyPass (configured in httpd.conf):

```
ProxyPass /nodeapp http://localhost:9009
```

My application uses Passport to authenticate users, so when I access the base path I should be redirected to the login page:

-- old redirect: http://example.com:9009 --> http://example.com:9009/login

-- new redirect: http://example.com/nodeapp --> http://example.com/nodeapp/login

Unfortunately, the redirect is not working:

-- broken redirect: http://example.com/nodeapp --> http://example.com/login

I have tried to enable proxy configuration in express, but this made no difference:

```
 app.enable('trust proxy');
```

** EDIT: **
As suggested by Ethan in the comments below, I can hardcode all my paths to suit the new environment, however this will then break the paths when running on my local machine at root ('/').

I looking for a more centralised solution which can adapt to different runtime environments if possible?

Comment: It looks like you're not redirecting to the right page.  Your new app is rooted at `/nodeapp`, but you're trying to redirect to `/login`.  In Passport, you can provide the `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` paths...you need those to start with `/nodeapp`.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, your solution worked for me when using my app on the remote server. However when running the application on my local machine of course the paths are now incorrect. I'm looking for a more centralised solution which can adapt to different runtime environments?

Answer (score 1):

In order to work both ways, you need to calculate the proxy path or the local path for each request.

I'm using Nginx proxy, which injects "x-forwarded-for" and "x-forwarded-proto" (protocol of oringinal request). Dump "req.headers" to see what headers your proxy may pass on.

Create this in your Express config before routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  if (req.headers.hasOwnProperty('x-forwarded-for')) {
     // proxy in effect
     req.redirUrl = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto']
        + "://"
        + req.headers.host    // proxy
        // plus any proxy subdirs if needed 
        + "/"
        + proxy_subdir
     ;

  } else {
     // direct requeset
     req.redirUrl = req.protocol
        + "://"
        + req.headers.host
     ;
  }

  next();
});
```

You now have a req.redirUrl you can use at the start of any redirects, that will work under proxy or direct access:

```
res.redirect(req.redirUrl + "/redir_path");
```